# How can I justify a text in React Native? 'textAlign: justify' is broken

Tags: react-native, webkit, text-alignment, text-align, text-justify

How can I justify a text in React Native? Is there any alternative solution besides the Webkit solution?

Comment: `alignSelf: center`

Comment: what do you mean by broken?